# Election STV data is already available

Tags: discussion, election

... even before results have been announced:

[image]

Comment: What site is that for? for Stack Overflow it still shows 56 minutes remaining (at this writing... Oops, 55 now).

Comment: Why is this a bug?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the STV data was only meant to be released after a few days... let me find the link...

Comment: @George, the SU and SF elections ended an hour earlier than the SO election.

Comment: @Farseeker according to the election page, as soon as it's over the data is available.

Comment: @george - yeah I just read that too. My mistake.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). There's no reason to wait until the announcement is made to release the data; the winners won't change based on who runs the calculator, after all.